# Spring security 4 @PreAuthorize(hasAuthority()) access denied

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-annotations

I am trying to convert a Spring Security 3 @Secured("admin") annotation into Spring Security 4 compatible fashion.

This is my `usersService.java`

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin')")
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return usersDao.getAllUsers();
}
```

Then in `security-context.xml` I have:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="permitAll" />
...
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

`getAllUsers()` is called by a `LoginController.java`

```
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public String showAdmin(Model model) {
    List<User> users = usersService.getAllUsers();

    model.addAttribute("users", users);

    return "admin";
}
```

In mySql database, there are two tables, users and authorities. `authorities` has 2 columns, username and authority. `administrator` has authority `admin`.

Now if I trie to access `/admin`, I will be redirected to `/login`, but after I log in with `administrator`, I still get "access denied".

I think I must have missed something very basic but as I am new to Spring, I could not figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Update: I tried changing the annotation to @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") and I also changed the "authority" column in mySql for admin from "admin" to "ROLE_ADMIN" but it still gives me 403. I did not have much faith on this because before this error, I had to change `hasRole('admin')` in `securityContext.xml` to `hasAuthority('admin')`.

Answer (score 22):

Although it's late, nevertheless

`hasRole(...)` set a prefix for the the content - the default one is `ROLE_`

`hasAuthority(...)` checks the content **WITHOUT** a prefix, i.e. just the pure content

Comment: Unfortunately, I am no longer working on this project. Thanks for the input, though.

Comment: I had the same issue (although I wasn't trying to migrate between versions) in which the authority wasn't working and this answer solved it. But I also had to add the annotation suggested by @Sohil

Answer (score 4):

You should add in Spring security

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")`

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I will update my question with a few details.